# Sidekiq is not starting on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, sidekiq, capistrano3

Can some one tell me what is wrong with this command and why `sidekiq` is not starting

```
run "cd #{release_path}/App && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec sidekiq -e #{fetch(:stage)} -C #{shared_path}/config/sidekiq.yml -P #{sidekiq_pid} -L #{shared_path}/log/sidekiq.log -d"
```

but capistrano is running this command

```
remote:   * executing "cd /home/user/applications/App/development/releases/00000000000001/App && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec sidekiq -e development -C /home/user/applications/App/development/shared/config/sidekiq.yml -P /home/user/applications/App/development/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /home/user/applications/App/development/shared/log/sidekiq.log -d"
remote:     servers: ["localhost"]
remote:     [localhost] executing command
remote:     command finished in 696ms
```

But still I have to start it manually even after `sidekiq` create `sidekiq.pid` file

Answer (score 1):

It may helpful for you :

**In config/initializers/sidekiq.rb  :**

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
end

**In config/sidekiq.yml :**

---

:concurrency: 5
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
  - [mailers, 2]

**In config/routes.rb :**

require "sidekiq/web"

mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"

Comment: I had already added these lines in my initializer file but don't know why it is still happening

Comment: you also added this config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq  In  config/application.rb ?

Comment: What is the use of above line means why should I include this line ?

Comment: @BrahamShakti: if you are using active job, you need to tell it to use Sidekiq.